# Angle between two vectors in an n-th dimensional space, where n is greater than 3

Tags: vectors

Suppose A and B are two non-parallel vectors. Where $ A $ and $ B $ are given as
$ A =(a_1, a_2, a_3,.....a_n) $ and
$ B  =(b_1, b_2, b_3,.....b_n) $
How can I geometrically determine the angle $ θ $ between the two vectors A and B?
I know that $ A.B = \left\lVert A \right\rVert \left\lVert B \right\rVert \cos(θ) $

Comment: Just calculate the elements in the equation and solve for $\cos(\theta)$ and finally find $\theta$.

Comment: What if n approaches infinity?

Comment: I want to be helped by the geometrical solution because the two vectors are beyond the realm of 2-D

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\theta&=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{A\cdot B}{\left\lVert A \right\rVert \left\lVert B \right\rVert}\right)\\
&=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(a_1, a_2, a_3,.....a_n)\cdot (b_1, b_2, b_3,.....b_n)}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^na^2_k}\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2}}\right)\\&
=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^na^2_k}\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2}}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Can I be helped by the geometrical solution? Because such vectors exist beyond 3-Dimensions.